# Setting environment variable in PyDev when running unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, pydev, nose

I'm using PyDev and testing with nose. Is there a way I can set an environment variable inside of PyDev only when I run unit tests?

thanks

Comment: Can you not set the variable in your test setup and then reset it in your teardown?

Comment: Well, probably. That's the less attractive alternative since I'd have to do that in every unit test.

Comment: No you wouldn't, nose supports lots of levels/types of test fixtures. You can even do package-level: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#fixtures And even without nose, you could always create a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` that performs the necessary work in its `setUp` and `tearDown` methods and then use that for your test classes (for that matter, the current version of `unittest` provides multiple test fixture layers as well).

Comment: Awesome. I feel kind of dumb for not suspecting such a thing existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comments into a proper answer: As nose supports multiple levels of test fixtures, even package-level, and even without nose `unittest.TestCase` supports `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods (and starting with Python 3.2, `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` as class methods, as well as the module-level `setUpModule()` and `tearDownModule()`), it's easy to perform common initialization and post-testing operations such as setting environment variables, etc. without having to place the necessary code within each test function or even having to explicitly call the test fixture functions.